# I'm the only one who can get my workflow to work

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have SharePoint Online. I created a workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013 that is fairly simple:

[image]

When I have tested the workflow - it sends all the emails & notifications that it is supposed to. I am the site collection administrator. However - if any user adds an item (and they have contribute access) the workflow it won't kick off and is suspended with the following error:

[image: error]

I am at a loss as to how to solve this or what could be causing this.

Comment: Are you sending mail to a single user or group for review?

Comment: Two individual users.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this thread: [Set user permissions required to run workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112167/set-user-permissions-required-to-run-workflow)

Something which I think could relate to your problem is this bit: If you look at a workflow's properties you can see there's a checkbox for "Allow this workflow to be manually started by an authenticated user with Edit Item permissions".
So obviously users with "edit item" can execute a workflow.

Alternatively, have a look at the top answer which explains using an Impersonation Step.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'm new to SharePoint Online  (previous experience is SharePoint 2010).  I don't understand in your link what they mean by "App Pool Account". 




I'm confused why SharePoint Online doesn't inherit site permissions on a workflow? In theory - if someone has contribute level access to a site they shouldn't have an issue.  




My settings in designer are allow workflow to manually start/start workflo when item is created or changed. Given my design above and these settings - what should I change?




I appreciate all the help I can get! :)

Comment: Also - as a side note. I have two accounts (Admin & Regular user) in SharePoint online. I created the workflow with my user account. I have set my user account as site owner - workflow worked. I removed site owner access and gave myself contributor - workflow worked. When the users who need the workflow try - they are able to successfully ad an item to the list but workflow won't kick off. They have contribute access to site.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try to create a log within your workflow just as a best practice.  Maybe it wouldn't help with this problem, but for others in the future, if you put log "whatever" after each action, it makes it A TON easier to troubleshoot.