# Workflow does not trigger even by Users having Contribute permissions to List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, permissions

First I gave a User (say UserA) with ***Contribute*** *minus* ***Delete*** rights to a List. When User A created items workflow did not trigger.

Then I read [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Is-Contribute-permissions-required-to-start-a-workflow/td-p/73161) ***contribute*** perms are required to get the workflow started so I gave the User A ***contribute*** perms but workflow didn't start on item creation by User A (workflow only runs when I create list item). It is the simplest Workflow and is set to start auto when item is created.

[image: Image for info]

[image: Image for info]

Now [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112167/set-user-permissions-required-to-run-workflow/163887#163887) it says ***Edit*** is required to get the workflow started.. All i know is ***Edit*** *>* ***Contribute***. Edit OR Contribute workflow does not trigger if User is not part of Site Owners group. My brain is literally like WTF right now. Kindly help!

Comment: Add the workflow in app step and workflow should trigger post that.

Comment: @Deepmala Putting Email action in app step does not work. User has to be part of **Site Owner** group which has Full Control to have the workflow execute through all steps... if I add in the user individually in List permissions and give Full control it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes i think i found a solution and have totally forgotten when and where it appeared. It was 3 years ago

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, user with at least contribute permission to get the workflow started.

For your issue that user with contribute permission cannot start the workflow, Make sure the user has user profile. That is to say you have to sync the user to SharePoint user profile service application.